# Check if user is logged in New Facebook API

Tags: facebook

well I'm new to the facebook api stuff, and just recently someone told me I was using the old api.

So now, I can't seem to figure out how to check if the user is logged into my site with the new api.

all I really have is

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: '(appid)', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
      // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
    } else {
      // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
    }
  });
</script>
```

and a login button.

If anyone could show me how to check if someones logged in, (or is that it right there?) because I'd like it to change the login button located in a div called

`<div id="fbuser">`

to welcome the user.

Or even if you can point me towards some useful tutorials, that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is an example where `fbLoginStatus()` function will be automatically called when user logs in/logs out, so you can decide which div to display there.

```html
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  function fbLoginStatus(response) {
     if( response.status === 'connected' ) {
        //user is logged in, display profile div
     } else {
        //user is not logged in, display guest div
     }
  }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(fbLoginStatus);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', fbLoginStatus);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Now if you need to check if user is logged in right now (for example on button click):

```js
if(FB.getSession() != null) {
   //logged user id: FB.getSession().uid
} else {
  //user is not logged in
}
```

Sorry, don't know any good tutorials.

Comment: Hey, Really nice one. Thank you so much. Did the 2nd bit give any one "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined"

Comment: can anyone suggest any php alternative