# check if the user log-in to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I develop application on facebook.this app can post to the user wall when he read any article on my website if he logged in to facebook. and everything work correctly but I want to do something i want my app to check if the users logged in to facebook or not if not the app must enforce him to logged in to facebook before he can read any article.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="452488354765730" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="3eesho reading club" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://3eesho.com/fb/subhitest/test_PAGE"  />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="3eesho.com" />
    <meta property="og:image"       content="http://ogp.me/logo.png" /> 
</head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
if (x==c_name)
{
return unescape(y);
}
}
}
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
function checkCookie()
{
var a=document.location.href;
var b=a.split("/");
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username==null || username=="")
{
alert("thank you for visit this Id:"+b[4]);
username=b[4];
myFunction();
setCookie("username",username,365);
}
else 
{
alert("this Id visited:"+b[4]);
if(username!=b[4])
{
myFunction();
setCookie("username",b[4],365);
}   
}
}
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("did you want to publish this article to your wall on facebook");
if (r==true)
{
x=alert("the article published!");
graphStreamPublish();
}
else
{
x=alert("the article doesn't publish!");
}
}
</script>
<script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                                            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                                            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                                            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                                            js.src =   "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=452488354765730";
                                            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
//FB App Script
            var button;
            var userInfo;
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                            FB.init({ appId: '452488354765730',
                            status: true,
                            cookie: true,
                            xfbml: true,
                            oauth: true});
                            showLoader(true);
            };
            (function() {
                            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                            e.src = document.location.protocol
                            + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
            //stream publish method
            function graphStreamPublish(){
                                alert("graphStreamPublish");
                            showLoader(true);
                            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',
                            {
                             message :    "\u0642\u0631\u0627 \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0642\u0627\u0644 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0639\u064A\u0634\u0648.\u0643\u0648\u0645",   
                                              link    : document.location.href+'? utm_campaign=spring&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=exampleblog'+target="_blank",
                                              },
                            function(response) {
                                            showLoader(false);
                                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                            //alert('Error occured');
                                            } 
                                                  else
    {

        alert("Posted as "+response.id);
    }
                            });
            }
            function showLoader(status){
                            if (status)
                                              document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
                            else
                                            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
            }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="checkCookie()">Testing</a>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="180" data-max-rows="1"  scope="publish_actions"></div>
                <div id="loader" style="display:none"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please search before you make a quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233560/possible-to-find-out-whether-a-user-is-logged-into-facebook-over-javascript-api

Comment: i do my search but the Solutions doesn't work with me so i was think i can found the solution here

Comment: What is it that isn't working? Ben's example in the link I attached should do exactly what you want. Then, if the user is not logged in, ask them to.