# Display facebook recommendations plugin when user is logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to display the facebook recommendations plugin when user is login into facebook.  I don't want to show the plugin when user is not logged into facebook because the result looks unpleasing.  Is this even possible?  How would I implement this to my site?

Thank you in adavance!
Maca

facebook social plugin (Recommendations)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/

I already have the Javascript SDK like below implemented in the page.  I also have jQuery1.5.2 loaded in the page.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div> <script>  
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
         FB.init({
           appId  : 'APP ID',
           status : true, // check login status
           cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
           xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
          channelUrl  : 'http://urltomysite.com/channel.html' // custom channel
         });   }; 

       (function() {
         var e = document.createElement('script');
         e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
         e.async = true;
         document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
     }());</script>
```

Here is the tag for recomendations plugin

```
<fb:recommendations site="urltomysite.com" width="300" height="300" header="true" font="" border_color=""></fb:recommendations>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "result looks unpleasing"? cos I've used it in my site and it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FB.getLoginSTatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to check if a user is logged into FB. With the response from this function, you can decide whether to show your recommendation or not.

```
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.session) {
         // logged in and connected user, someone you know
        } else {
        // no user session available, someone you dont know
        }
  });
```

Also Check : [Check if user is logged in New Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348543/check-if-user-is-logged-in-new-facebook-api)

Comment: I know Im asking too much but I just started to learn Javascript. I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to work. 

`function fbLoginStatus(response) {
       if(response.session) {
        document.getElementById('fb-root').innerHTML = "<fb:recommendations site='url.com' width='300' height='300' header='false' border_color=''></fb:recommendations>";
        } else {
          document.getElementById('fb-root').innerHTML = "<p>YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN</p>";
        }
     }`

Comment: Check the console if you are getting any error, if yes what is the error, and I'm not sure I can tell anything without knowing what error you are getting as the js seems to be fine.